# POST array of dynamic form fields objects in Express, Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm trying to create a form where the users can dynamically anothers student to a form. The form should be submitted to the server as an array of students, each with a first and last name.

Desired outcome:

```
[
  {
    first_name: "Bob",
    last_name: "Smith"
  },
  {
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Joe"
  }
]
```

For some reason the code below puts all the first_name 's and all the last_name 's into arrays when the form is submitted. Specifying `name="students[][first_name]"` doesn't seem to solve the problem for me.

Actual outcome:

```
[
  {
    "first_name": [
      "Bob",
      "John"
    ],
    "last_name": [
      "Smith",
      "Joe"
    ]
  }
]
```

HTML

```
<form class="col-md-5" action="/insert" method="post">
  <div class="form-group" id="student-controls">
    <div class="student-entry input-group">
      <input name="students[][first_name]" class="form-control param-name" type="text"/>
      <input name="students[][last_name]" class="form-control col-md-2 param-unit-type" type="text"/>
      <button class="btn btn-success student-add" type="button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS (to dynamically add student form fields)

```
$(document).on('click', '.student-add', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var controlDiv = $('#student-controls'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.student-entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlDiv);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlDiv.find('.student-entry:not(:last) .student-add')
        .removeClass('student-add').addClass('student-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
}
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/insert', function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.students, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `students[first_name][]`?

Comment: Ya I get:   {
    "first_name": [
      "Bob",
      "John"
    ],
    "last_name": [
      "Smith",
      "Joe"
    ]
  }

Comment: Hmm okay, let me see if I find a workaround

Comment: I could manually do it by looping over all the students... but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the cleanest way... but it works. The idea is that the HTML contains

```
<input name="students[0][first_name]" class="form-control param-name" type="text" />
<input name="students[0][last_name]" class="form-control col-md-2 param-unit-type" type="text" />
```

Then, on the `click` handler, after you add a new `div`, you edit all the inputs so that they are properly indexed.

```
newEntry.appendTo(controlDiv);

$(".student-entry input[name*=first_name]").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'students[' + i + '][first_name]');
});

$(".student-entry input[name*=last_name]").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'students[' + i + '][last_name]');
});
```

This produces this output:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "first_name": "luke",
      "last_name": "skywalker"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "han",
      "last_name": "solo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that for this to work, `bodyParser` must be configured with `extended: true`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```